# I'm trying to count the numbers in a string in C

Tags: c

What's wrong with my code? I'm trying to count the numbers in a string after skipping all alphabets.

How to skip the alphabets and only count the numbers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(char a[])
{
    int i=0,count=0;
    while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(a[i]>='a'&&a[i]<='z')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        char a[100001];
        scanf("%s",a);
        function(a);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `continue` does not jump to `i++`. It jumps past `i++`.

Comment: out of @GSerg remark  `if(a[i]>='a'&&a[i]<='z')` is not enough, you missed to manages A..Z. Why not using *ìsalpha*? However to not have an alpha does not means you have a digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I switched your usage of `scanf` to use `fgets`. This works:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void function(char a[])
{
    int i=0,count=0;
    while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        if (isdigit(a[i]))
        {
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
}

int main()
{
    int t = 0;

    scanf("%d", &t);

    while(t--)
    {
        char a[100001];
        fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin);
        function(a);
        puts("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: the OP speaks about the number of *numbers*, not the number of *digits*. in "a12b" there is 1 number but 2 digits.

Comment: Maybe so, but the OP's original code processed and printed each digit individually. Counting out groups of digits would require a different approach

Answer (score 0):

If the OP's intent was in fact to count up the groups of digits (in which the definition of 'number' is each contiguous run of digits), this will accomplish the goal:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int function(char a[])
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    //  convert all non-digits to whitespace
    printf("Converting\n");
    for (char *p = a; *p != '\0'; ++p)
    {
        *p = isdigit(*p) ? *p : ' ';
    }

    printf("Found Groups: %s\n",a);
    // note: strtok mutates the string it is given, it will not be usable after this:
    for (char *gr = strtok(a," "); gr != NULL; gr = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        cnt++;
    }
    printf("Number of Groups: %d\n", cnt);

}
int main()
{
    printf("Enter strings (Ctrl-C to end)\n");
    while(1)
    {
        int result = 0;
        char a[100001];
        scanf("%s",a);
        result = function(a);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

(I was not able to get the version using `fgets` to work, but how the string is gathered is not really in the scope of the question, the OP's original code in `main` is functional, I just made it an open-ended loop for my tests)

Answer (score -1):

In your code continue statement is responsible for wrong answer. Because of it your code is not encountering the statement a[i] !='\0'. so suggest you to just avoid it and close your if statement without any code as like me. One more suggestion use also uppercase letters as user can also enter uppercase letters and using fgets() function you can also read white spaces.
Try out this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function(char a[])
{
   int i=0,count=0;
  while(a[i]!='\0')
 {
        if((a[i]>='a'&&a[i]<='z') || (a[i]>='A'&&a[i]<='Z'));
       else
      {
         count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",count);
}

int main()
{
   int t;
  scanf("%d",&t);
 while(t--)
    {
       char a[100001];
      scanf("%s",a);
     function(a);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```